# Encountered " <INTEGER_LITERAL> in Big Query SQL statement

Tags: google-bigquery

trying to query my data Google Big Query [web explorer](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com). The query is met to return result with a specified time range. The sql statement is corrent but it still gives me the error

```
Error: Encountered " <INTEGER_LITERAL> "10 "" at line 6, column 37. Was expecting: <EOF>
```

SQL statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM data.example WHERE timeCollected >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

. Am I missing anything i should have implemented. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For time arithmetic use DATE_ADD instead.

```
DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), -10, 'minute')
```